# How to Customize vim for scripting in Python 3 ?

Tags: vim, python-3.x

I am new to vim and I want to use it for scripting Python3. anyone knows how to customize vim for editing Python 3 scripts? (mainly for indentations, coloring and tab suggestions... )

Thanks

Comment: There are several blog posts and SO questions about "Vim as a Python IDE". What have you tried so far?

Comment: See, eg. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14527902/vim-as-a-python-ide/14528068#14528068, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10278560/python-interpreter-shell-with-vim-integration-possible/10278718#10278718 and http://sontek.net/blog/detail/turning-vim-into-a-modern-python-ide. A quick google search will turn up lots of useful information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Python wiki](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Vim) suggests putting the following in your `~/.vimrc`:

```
syntax on
filetype indent plugin on
set tabstop=8
set expandtab
set shiftwidth=4
set softtabstop=4
```

Edit: the above does have the side-effect of using the tab settings in **all** files edited with vim. Other approaches are discussed in the [wiki](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Vim) as well.

There's also the [python.vim](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=790) script for syntax highlighting and such.

Comment: The two first line should be at the top of every `/.vimrc` but the other ones are somewhat python-specific. As such, they should be in `~/.vim/after/ftplugin/python.vim` with `setlocal` instead of `set`.

Answer (score 1):

You should put customized settings in to `~/.vim/ftplugin/python.vim` This will be sourced when vim sees a file with a filetype python.

To make sure the settings only affect the current buffer use `setlocal`.

To make sure that mappings only affect the current buffer use `noremap <buffer>`

Just make sure to have `filetype plugin indent on` in `~/.vimrc`